# How to insert Pandas DataFrame into Cassandra?

Tags: python, pandas, cassandra

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df

date        time       open   high   low   last
01-01-2017  11:00:00   37      45     36    42
01-01-2017  11:23:00   36      43     33    38
01-01-2017  12:00:00   45      55     35    43

....
```

I want to write it into cassandra. It's kind of bulk upload after processing on data in python.

The schema for cassandra is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE ks.table1(date text, time text, open float, high float, low 
                       float, last float, PRIMARY KEY(date, time))
```

To insert single row into cassandra we can use cassandra-driver in python but I couldn't find any details about uploading an entire dataframe.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

session.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO ks.table1 (date,time,open,high,low,last)
    VALUES (01-01-2017, 11:00:00, 37, 45, 36, 42)
    """)
```

P.S:  The similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280412/insert-pandas-dataframe-into-cassandra-table) have been asked earlier, but doesn't have answer to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even i was facing this problem but i figured out that even while uploading Millions of rows(19 Million to be exact) into Cassandra its didn't take much time.

Coming to your problem,you can use [cassandra Bulk LOADER](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated) 
to get your job done.

EDIT 1:

You can use prepared statements to help uplaod data into cassandra table while iterating through the dataFrame.

```
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
    cluster = Cluster(ip_address)
    session = cluster.connect(keyspace_name)
    query = "INSERT INTO data(date,time,open,high,low,last) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    prepared = session.prepare(query)
```

"?" is used to input variables

```
    for item in dataFrame:
        session.execute(prepared, (item.date_value,item.time_value,item.open_value,item.high_value,item.low_value,item.last_value))
```

## or

```
    for item in dataFrame:
        session.execute(prepared, (item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4],item[5]))
```

What i mean is that use for loop to extract data and upload using session.execute().

for more info on [prepared statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/python/3.2/api/cassandra/query.html)

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Nice option is to use batches. First you can split df into even partitions (thanks to [Python/Pandas - partitioning a pandas DataFrame in 10 disjoint, equally-sized subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570268/python-pandas-partitioning-a-pandas-dataframe-in-10-disjoint-equally-sized-su)) and then put each partition as batch into Cassandra. Batch size is limited by Cassandra (cassandra.yaml) setting:
`batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50`

The code for batch insert of Pandas df:

```
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
    from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
    from cassandra.query import BatchStatement

    CASSANDRA_PARTITION_NUM = 1500

    def write_to_cassandra(df):
        cassandra_cluster = Cluster('ip')
        session = cassandra_cluster.connect('keyspace')
        prepared_query = session.prepare('INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES (?,?)')
        for partition in split_to_partitions(df, CASSANDRA_PARTITION_NUM):
            batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
            for index, item in partition.iterrows():
                batch.add(prepared_query, (item.id, item.name))
            session.execute(batch)

    def split_to_partitions(self, df, partition_number):
        permuted_indices = np.random.permutation(len(df))
        partitions = []
        for i in range(partition_number):
            partitions.append(df.iloc[permuted_indices[i::partition_number]])
        return partitions
```

Update:
Do it only when batch is within the same partition.

Comment: Please don't use batches to inserting data into different partitions - you're adding more load to the nodes, and really decreasing throughput. Better option is to issue async requests... Here is more on "bad use" of batches: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame doesn't seem to work as expected in the first answer anymore.  Here is how I access the data in the df (the example below uses cassandra db):

```
        columns = list(df.columns.values)

        query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES({})".format(table, ','.join(columns), ','.join([val.replace(val, "?") for val in columns]))

        preparedquery = self.session.prepare(query)

        for row in df.loc:

            values = [row[col] for col in columns]

            self.session.execute(preparedquery, values)
```

There is an "not in range" error at the last row which I think it is pandas' bug.