COPY command in Python script returns “AssertionError: Attempted serializing to buffer exceeded maximum”
When I want to add data from CSV file as separated '\t', and I used COPY and Insert into in my Python script, but I got some error like:
Java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: \
   Attempted serializing to buffer exceeded maximum of 65535 bytes: 1700053

Code:
def pd_to_cassandra_type(pd_series):
    if pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(pd_series):
        return 'bigint'
    elif pd.api.types.is_float_dtype(pd_series):
        return 'double'
    else:
        return 'text'
    

def clean_column_name(name):
    name = re.sub(r'\W+', '_', name)
    if name[0].isdigit():
        name = '_' + name
    return name



def create_table(session, keyspace_name, table_name, column_definition):
    session.execute(f"""
    CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS {keyspace_name}
    WITH REPLICATION = {{ 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 }}
    """)

    session.set_keyspace(keyspace_name)

    session.execute(f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
        {column_definition},
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY
    )
    """)

def split_and_load_data():
    file_path = 'path/to/your/large_file.tab'
    keyspace_name = 'my_keyspace'
    table_name = "my_table"

    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter='\t')

    # Clean and reassign column names
    data.columns = [clean_column_name(col) for col in data.columns]

    user = "user_name"
    password = "1234"

    auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=user, password=password)
    cluster       = Cluster(["192.12.4.5"], auth_provider=auth_provider, connect_timeout=1000, control_connection_timeout=1000)
    session       = cluster.connect()
    column_definitions = ", ".join([f"{col}" text for col in data.columns]

    # İlk sütun grubuna göre tabloyu oluşturun
    create_table(session, keyspace_name, table_name, column_definitions)
    copy_command = f"cqlsh {"192.12.4.5"} -e \"COPY {keyspace}.{table} ({', '.join(data.columns)}) FROM '{file_path}' WITH DELIMITER='\t' AND HEADER=TRUE;\""
    subprocess.run(copy_command, shell=True, check=True)


CSV data size approximately 500 MB. Normally Cassandra should support to load the data, but I got some error.

Use your session object to upload the data, not cqlsh https://stackoverflow.com/q/49108809/2308683

Without (1) the full error message, and (2) the full stack trace, it's impossible to determine whether the AssertionError is related to the bulk load you are performing.
In any case, it is important to note that the cqlsh utility itself is a Python script which uses the Cassandra Python driver under the hood. It is not designed to be run within another Python script or application.
If you would like to import the contents of a CSV file programatically, the cqlsh COPY command is not the recommended way of doing it. Instead, you should iterate over the individual lines in the CSV then construct CQL INSERT statements using the field values as bind variables. Cheers!
